# HttpGet method with Http and Https Protocols return response 200 for Https but 404 for Http protocol

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, servlet-filters, http-get, orbeon

Facing a problem with protocols, please find the below code snippet.

If `rquestedUrl` starts with https, `getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` is returning 200 whereas if the same `rquestedUrl` starts with http, `getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` is returning 404.

But if I hit through browser I am able to access the requested file in both cases. Could you please let me know what could be the possible problems. (It is used as a filter before calling Orbeon, this is on the process of implementing WSSO.)

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path_to_JKSFile");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
String rquestedUrl = "http://bigminds.web.mindblow.com/project/project1/views/files/Home.xhtml";
HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(rquestedUrl);
get.addHeader("Cookie", "somevalues");
get.addHeader("Host", "bigminds.mindblow.com:14325");
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(get);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the endpoint you are hitting does not accept http requests, all requests must be though https. So there isn't anything wrong with your code, it's just not set up to properly integrate with the site you have there. Looking at the code it looks like you may need to have some type of session (ie: need to login) with the webserver to get the data you want.